# Looking for a vb.net code to add existing buttons/text boxes/drop down lists, etc. to a container, or holder?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, containers, placeholder, visible

I'm using vb.net. Basically, I have a drop down list, text box and a submit button. You choose a movie director from a drop down list, then type in a movie, click button and it adds the data to my database.

There's another button which hides/shows drop down list, text box and submit button using Visible = True and Visible = False, but what I don't like about it is when it hides the things I said before, it leaves some white/empty space like if they are still there, but not visible.

Is there anyway to put some kind of holder/container and place a button which when clicked could add my drop down list, text box and submit buttons to that place?

Cheers,
E.N.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are working with WinForms in Visual Studio. In the Toolbox the controls which could help you out of this situation are in the "Containers" section. Among others, there is a `Panel`, a `FlowLayoutPanel` and a `TableLayoutPanel` (see [this video on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb798032.aspx) for a `TableLayoutPanel` Demo). They can help you to organize controls. Especially the `FlowLayoutPanel` places the controls automatically. But you can always change the `Top` and the `Left` properties of any control, to move them around to the desired place or group some of them on a `Panel` and change the `Location` of this one one.

You can add a control to a container by using the `Add` method of its `Controls` property. However, if the control is already on the form (since you are asking how to add an existing control) you must remove it from the form before.

```
Me.Controls.Remove(myButton)
panel1.Controls.Add(myButton)
```

Comment: I'm not a good explainer, but let me try and explain it visually. I've made a screenshot and pointed a few things out, maybe it will be more understandable.

Here's the screenshot:
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/138/39565979.png/

Comment: The basic piece of information that was missing from your question was that you are working with `ASP.NET`. I added the corresponding tag. As you can see on your image, there is a `Panel` too in ASP.NET. Can't you just add the "Add Director"-controls on a panel in the designer and change the `Visible` property of the `Panel` programmatically in the page load event?

Comment: I'm sorry, I should've added more information. I'm pretty new to asp.net. Thank you for you assistance.